# C# Binary Tree's - Inorder/Preorder and PostOrder (Recursion Help)

Tags: c#, recursion, binary-tree

I need some help with recursion. I'm trying do a binary tree in C#, I'm wondering if it's possible to demonstrate all Inorder/PostOrder and PreOrder traversal with a recursive function.

I have completed it for PreOrder and then attempted InOrder however caused a StackOverflow Exception, my grasp on Binary Tree's is flimsy at best so any help with this would be much appreciated, even if it does seem like a stupid question.

The following code is what I'm using for PreOrder Traversal;

```
     public void recursivePreorder(BinaryTreeNode root)
    {
        Console.Write(root.Data.ToString());
        if (root.Left != null)
        {
            recursivePreorder(root.Left);
        }
        if (root.Right != null)
        {
            recursivePreorder(root.Right);
            }
    }

     public void preorderTraversal()
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
            recursivePreorder(Root);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no tree to process");
        }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Build the tree
        Test.Add(5);
        Test.Add(2);
        Test.Add(1);
        Test.Add(3);
        Test.Add(3); // Duplicates are OK
        Test.Add(4);
        Test.Add(6);
        Test.Add(10);
        Test.Add(7);
        Test.Add(8);
        Test.Add(9);
        // Test if we can find values in the tree

        for (int Lp = 1; Lp <= 10; Lp++)
            Console.WriteLine("Find Student ID ({0}) = {1}", Lp, Test.Find(Lp));

        // Test if we can find a non-existing value
        Console.WriteLine("Find Student ID (999) = {0}", Test.Find(999));

        // Iterate over all members in the tree -- values are returned in sorted order
        foreach (int value in Test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Preorder Traversal");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Test.preorderTraversal();
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Thanks in advance, this is definitely something I'm having trouble getting my head around and I'm not even sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inorder is very similar to what you already have, just move your code around a little bit in where you are handling the current node:

```
public void recursiveInorder(BinaryTreeNode root)
{
    if (root.Left != null)
    {
        recursiveInorder(root.Left);
    }
    Console.Write(root.Data.ToString());
    if (root.Right != null)
    {
        recursiveInorder(root.Right);
    }
}
```

The difference to preorder is just that you first traverse the left subtree, then process the current node and finally traverse the right subtree.

Comment: Thanks very much for the fast reply, any chance you could also show me PostOrder? And anychance you could help explain how it actually works for me? I'm just stuck on both how Binary Trees work and how recursion works because although your answer is perfectly clear I seem to be struggling with understanding anything surrounding this topic.

Comment: @SteffanCaine: Think about it for a second: *post* order just moves the processing of the current node last - so where would you place your `Console.Write` statement then? Also check out the wikipedia article that @Mitch linked below.

Comment: Ha, I knew it would be simple and with the article link below and your reply it is indeed very obvious. Thanks alot mate much appreciato ;)

Comment: We can add a validation at the starting of the method to check if root is null.

Answer (score 4):

The wiki page for [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) states:

> **Binary Tree**
>
> To traverse a non-empty binary tree in **preorder**, perform the following operations recursively at each node, starting
> with the root node:
>
> 1. Visit the root.
> 2. Traverse the left subtree.
> 3. Traverse the right subtree.
>
> To traverse a non-empty binary tree in **inorder** (symmetric), perform
> the following operations recursively at each node:
>
> 1. Traverse the left subtree.
> 2. Visit the root.
> 3. Traverse the right subtree.
>
> To traverse a non-empty binary tree in **postorder**, perform the
> following operations recursively at each node:
>
> 1. Traverse the left subtree.
> 2. Traverse the right subtree.
> 3. Visit the root.

[BTW, it was the first search hit.]

Comment: I've actually already got a document that attempts to explain this I just didn't get it so wanted a more human answer however that post you linked is very helpful so thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  class BstNode
    {
        public int data;
        public BstNode(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public BstNode left;
        public BstNode right;
    }
class Program
            {
                public static void PreOrderTraversal(BstNode root)
                {
                    if (root == null) return;

                    Console.WriteLine("PreOrderTraversal at node {0}", root.data); // process the root
                    PreOrderTraversal(root.left);// process the left
                    PreOrderTraversal(root.right);// process the right
                }

                public static void InOrderTraversal(BstNode root)
                {
                    if (root == null) return;

                    InOrderTraversal(root.left);// process the left
                    Console.WriteLine("InOrderTraversal at node {0}", root.data); // process the root
                    InOrderTraversal(root.right);// process the right
                }

                public static void PostOrderTraversal(BstNode root)
                {
                    if (root == null) return;

                    PostOrderTraversal(root.left);// process the left            
                    PostOrderTraversal(root.right);// process the right
                    Console.WriteLine("PostOrderTraversal at node {0}", root.data); // process the root
                }
        }
```